# How do I mute notification sounds from a specific app using ADB?

Tags: android, audio, notifications, adb

Trying to stop "Kijiji" from making noise every time I get a reply but the app has no way to disable the notification sound.

Any way to disable the notification sounds via ADB? I know you can disable vibration for specific apps so I think you can disable notification sounds also.

Comment: Using adb we can not disable notification sound for specific apps.